# Paste multi-line text into single-line Edit Box control

Tags: mfc, controls, dialog, components, editbox

My app uses standard single-line Edit Box controls. Is there any way to accept a multi-line "paste", discarding carriage return / linefeeds?

Notes
I *don't* want to use multi-line controls
My app is VS2010 C++ with WTL (not MFC or ATL)
The *reason* I want this is because actual input is normally quite short, but could in rare circumstances be hundreds or even thousands of characters. In which case users might well want to build the string using NotePad or whatever, then just cut & paste it in.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as the user is pasting himself/herself. An alternative is to use a multi-line Edit Box and displaying all the data into one line by managing the pasted data into OnChange function for your control (basically disregading new lines).

Comment: I guess I'm not going to find what I was hoping for - either some alternative control, or a way to hook into the input keystrokes as they arrive, so I can discard CR / LF immediately. I'll leave this one open for a bit on the off-chance, but hopes are fading.